# Colorful glass material on aeroplane

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, color, glass

How do I get that effect on the glass just like the one shown in the pic below[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109899/how-to-create-this-colorful-metal-material

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

Surface: Principled BSDF
Roughness: 0
Transmission: 1

In the material settings, enable Screen Space Refraction

In Eevee:

Enable Screen Space Reflections and within that, Enable Refraction

The last step is to go back to the material and set the IOR (Index of Refraction) from 1.45 to 1.00.  That will make the material completely transparent like glass.

Then, adjust the Metallic value of the material to give you that mirror-like reflection you're looking for.

Finally, to get the irridescence click on the dot to the right of the Base Color and select Noise Texture.  Set the Dimension to 3D, and adjust the Scale, Detail, and Distortion to your liking.  I found Scale = 2.5, Detail = 1.0, Distortion = 0.1 worked pretty well.

You can dig into this further by going into the Shading Editor and working with this directly with nodes, but this approach gives you what you're looking for without getting into that detail:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate :) very helpful